# Manipulate YouTube Playlist API in tableview using Alamofire

Tags: ios, youtube, swift3, cocoapods, alamofire

I have searched around to find an answer for my issue, but I had no luck. I'm new in coding, especially with Swift 3.0.

I'm trying to parse a YouTube playlist dynamically in a tableview using Alamofire cocoa pod in my project. My project contains: a viewcontroller called "videosViewController" which holds the tableview, a class called "Video", which holds the items I'm parsing from youtube API, and another class called "VideoModel" holds the method to pare those items. When I run my project the console parse the items successfully, but then the project crashes at the line of code:

```
for video in (data["items"] as? NSDictionary)!
```

with "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10d2ebd88) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10d2ec288)." error as shown below

[Project crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XIiv.png)

[Console details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxSWo.png)

And here the snippet of code I used:

videosViewController:

```
 import UIKit

 class videosViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,      UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var videos:[Video] = [Video]()
var selectedVideo: Video?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let model = VideoModel()

     model.fetchVideos()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return (self.view.frame.size.width / 320)  * 180
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return videos.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasicCell")!

    let videoTitle = videos[indexPath.row].videoTitle
    let label = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    label.text = videoTitle

    let videoThumbnailUrlString = "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/" + videos[indexPath.row].videoId + "/maxresdefault.jpg"

    let videoThumbnailUrl = NSURL(string: videoThumbnailUrlString)

    if videoThumbnailUrl != nil {

        let request = URLRequest(url: videoThumbnailUrl! as URL)

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request,
                                    completionHandler: { (data:Data?,
                                        response:URLResponse?,
                                        error:Error?) -> Void in

                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView


                                        imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

                                        }


        })



    task.resume()
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedVideo = self.videos[indexPath.row]

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetail", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let detailView = segue.destination as! videoDetailViewController

    detailView.selectedVideo = self.selectedVideo
}



}
```

The Video class:

```
import UIKit

class Video: NSObject {

var videoId:String = ""
var videoTitle:String = ""
var videoDescription:String = ""
var videoThumbnailURL = ""

}
```

And the VideoModel class:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class VideoModel: NSObject {

let parameters: Parameters = ["part":"snippet","playlistId":"PLMRqhzcHGw1ZRUB86rmNqG15Sr5jV-2NU","key":"AIzaSyDdNXhz3H7ifXB-qfOVakz0Xps2Y-kP0R0"]

var videoArray = [Video]()

func fetchVideos() {


    Alamofire.request("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in


        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(let JSON):
            print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")



            if let data = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                // print(response.result.value)

                var arrayOfVideos = [Video]()

                for video in (data["items"] as? NSDictionary)! {

                    let videoObj = Video()


                    videoObj.videoId = (video.value as? NSDictionary)?["snippet.resourceId.videoId"] as? String ?? ""
                    videoObj.videoTitle = (video.value as? NSDictionary)?["snippet.title"] as? String ?? ""
                    videoObj.videoDescription = (video.value as? NSDictionary)?["snippet.description"] as? String ?? ""
                    videoObj.videoThumbnailURL = (video.value as? NSDictionary)?["snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url"] as? String ?? ""

                    print(video)

                    // You need to parse the items into the video data
                    arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj)
                }



                self.videoArray = arrayOfVideos

                // }



            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `data["items"]` is an array, but you're grabbing it as a dictionary. I don't know exactly what the returned data looks like, but I'm guessing its `items` key probably holds an array of dictionaries. `(data["items"] as? NSArray)` might work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I followed your suggestion I received some errors as shown: 'Value of type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') has no member 'value''

Comment: How can I rewrite the items inside this array?

Comment: What are you expecting `video` to be? You probably need to tell it what to expect. I would try using `guard let videoAsType = video as? <ExpectedClassOfVideo> else { // handle error case}` (or similarly, an `if let`) and then read from `videoAsType` instead of `video` for `video.value`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
as? NSDictionary
```

with

```
as? [String:Any]
```

in

```
for video in (data["items"] as? NSDictionary)!
```

Bcs: You have to cast type Any to Swift dictionary type [String:Any].

```
if let JSON = response.result.value  as?  [String : Any] {
   if let items =  JSON["items"] as? [[String : Any]] {
        for video in items {
              //Other code
        }
   }
```

}